# Mongoose references: Should documents cross reference each other

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I need some input on schema design with mongodb and mongoose.

I have the following scenario data entities:

- Posts
- Comments
- Users

Requirements:

A user can make a comment on a post.
Comments can be served for a post.
A list of all comments of a user can be retrieved.

---

I'm thinking to make all 3 of them a seperate schema and connect them by using `ref`.

I see two approaches here and need input on what might be smarter. Should every entity link to its relations or is it enough if only the comments are a "link" to the other data objects?

```
export const commentSchema = new Schema<CommentDocument>({
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    userId: { required: true, type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
    postId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "post" },
});
```

And then for both user and post, should they also link to the comment again or is it enough if the relationship is stored once in comment?

```
export const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>({
  // ... all my user data
comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "comment" }] // <--- Is the referencing on the other documents useful?
});
```

```
export const postSchema = new Schema<PostDocument>({
  // ... all my post data
comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "comment" }] // <--- Is the referencing on the other documents useful?
});
```

Is there any rule of thumb for declaring the references between the documents? Is this generally a good  schema design approach?

Answer (score 0):

your `commentSchema` is good
But no need to store commentsId in `userSchema`& `postSchema`.
Because, it will be good for fews comment but for large no of comments it is not a good approach.

Comment: So you would just get all the comments for a post by searching the comments model for the correct post it is associated to?

Comment: If you find comments of a particular post.. Search using postId  and if you want to search all the comments of a user then search by userId.

if data is huge,you can add pagination on server-side